# UnsupportedClassVersionError from running Stanford Chinese Segmenter

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, text-segmentation, unsupported-class-version

I am getting UnsupportedClassVersionError when running the Stanford Chinese Segmenter. I have seen other post saying that this results from not updating to the newest Java version. As seen below in the screenshot, I have the latest Java updated on my mac yet the problem remains.

[image]

Comment: Open Terminal, and type `java -version`, and add the result to your question, please. Your screenshot only shows the java version of the JRE, *not* the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

So after I checked my system using `java -version` it shows that it is still in 1.6 version. The way to resolve this problem is to download jdk from Oracle website.